# How to apply CSS, only in child grid in kendo Angular

Tags: css, angular, kendo-grid

[Image shows how grid looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjZaV.jpg)

I have implemented an angular UI using kendo. It contains a nested grid. I want to apply css only in child grid. But when I am going to write css it also applied into parent grid also. How to do that.

Grid Structure like this:

```
Row 1
   row 1
   row 2
Row 2
    row 1
Row 3
    row 1
```

I have tried this

```
::ng-deep .k-grid td {
    padding: 8px !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="monitorGrid container-fluid pt-2 pr-0 pl-0">
  <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [resizable]="true">
    <kendo-grid-column [width]="140" field="shipmentAutoId" title="Shipment Auto Id"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="shipmentName" [width]="550" title="Shipment Name"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="shipmentStatusId" hidden="hidden" title="Shipment Status Id"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="statusName" [width]="140" title="Shipment Status"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="pdfCount" [width]="90" title="PDF count"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="downloadDate" [width]="140" title="Download Date"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="deliveryDate" [width]="180" title="Shipment Delivery Date"></kendo-grid-column>
    <ng-template let-dataItem kendoGridDetailTemplate>

      <kendo-grid class="childGrid" [data]="dataItem.processing" [resizable]="true">
        <kendo-grid-column field="processingId" [width]="110" title="Processing Id">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="documentName" [width]="520" title="Document Name">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="insuranceCoId" hidden="hidden" title="Insurance Co Id">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="insuranceCoName" [width]="145" title="Insurance Co Name">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="templateId" hidden="hidden" title="Template Id">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="templateName" title="Template Name"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="sparteId" hidden="hidden" title="Sparte Id">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="sparte" [width]="70" title="Sparte"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="gevoId" hidden="hidden" title="Gevo Id"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="gevo" [width]="90" title="Gevo"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="totalPages" [width]="100" title="Total Pages">
        </kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>

    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid>

</div>
```

Expected result: Style like color and padding width only applied in Child grid.

Actual result: Css applies all in the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you make a CSS rule that targets your child grid:

```css
::ng-deep .childGrid td {
    padding: 8px !important;
}
```